# XmlSerializer - How can I set a default when deserializing an enum?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, defensive-programming

I have a class that looks like this (heavily simplified):

```
public class Foo
{
    public enum Value
    {
        ValueOne,
        ValueTwo
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public Value Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I'm receiving an XML file from an external source. Their documentation states that the Foo element will only ever have "ValueOne" or "ValueTwo" in the Bar attribute (they don't supply an XSD).

So, I deserialize it like this:

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
 var xml = "<Foo Bar=\"ValueTwo\" />";
 var reader = new StringReader(xml);

 var foo = (Foo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

... and that all works.

However, last night, they sent me some XML looking like *this* instead, and my deserialization failed (as it should):`<Foo Bar="" />`

Is there a good way to defensively code around this? Ideally I'd like to say something like "default to ValueOne, if something goes wrong here". I don't want to throw away the whole XML file, because a single attribute was mangled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1266758/485076

Comment: You could try creating an XML object from your input string first, then iterate over the nodes and replace all empty values with ValueOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually parse enum value by creating another property with the same XmlAttribute name:

```
public enum Value
{
    // Default for unknown value
    Unknown,
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo
}

[XmlIgnore]
public Value Bar { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("Bar")]
public string _Bar
{
    get { return this.Bar.ToString(); }
    set { this.Bar = Enum.TryParse(value, out Value enumValue) ? enumValue : Value.Unknown; }
}
```

Usage the same as your before

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
var xml = "<Foo Bar=\"invalid value\" />";
var reader = new StringReader(xml);
var foo = (Foo)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Nearly 10 years later, and I've just gone back to check the code I wrote at the time... It's almost identical to your answer. Nice to finally mark this as answered!

Comment: @NeilD I hope this answer will help someone else in next 10 years

Answer (score 4):

you can set you enum like this , so this will set "" value of enum to Unknown = 0 somewhat like default value

```
public enum Foo
{
   [XmlEnum(Name = "")]
   Unknown =0,
   [XmlEnum(Name = "Single")]
   One,
   [XmlEnum(Name = "Double")]
   Two   
}
```

more detail check : [**XmlEnumAttribute Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx)

Comment: Hmm... That's a decent option, but it does require that I know all of the potential bad values ahead of time. I'd like something that will cope if they send "", or "ValueThree", or "SomethingTotallyRandom".

Answer (score 0):

Shoot down `XmlSerializer`..
Use **LINQ2XML** for this simple task

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourStreamXML"); 

List<Foo> yourList=doc.Descendants("Foo")
.Select(x=>
new Foo
{
    Bar=(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Value)).Contains(x.Attribute("Bar").Value))?((this.Value)x.Attribute("Bar")):(this.Value.ValueOne);
}
).ToList<Foo>();
```

So,I am basically doing this

```
if(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Value)).Contains(x.Attribute("Bar").Value))
//if the xml bar value is a valid enum
    Bar=(this.Value)x.Attribute("Bar");
else//xml bar value is not a valid enum..so use the default enum i.eValueOne
    Bar=this.Value.ValueOne;
```

Comment: I think the Foo class is much bigger, and author tries to avoid manual deserialization

Comment: Yup, the real XML and class structure is HUGE! It would be a big job to refactor everything to work with Linq2Xml.