# XML Deserialization in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have one class which was serialized before. We have the xml output from it.
When we open the project we deserialize the xml to get the preserved objects.
Now i have added new bool property to class and since it is a new property, old xmls don't have this attribute. My deserialization works fine but assigns false to bool property, I want it to set true if its not there in XML. How can i achieve this ? I tried like this

```
public bool? _flag;
[XmlElement("Flag")]
public bool? flag
{
    get
    {
        if (null != _flag)
        {
            return _flag;
        }
        return true;
    }
    set { _flag= value; }
}
```

Comment: Deserialization skips initialization, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266547/how-do-you-find-out-when-youve-been-loaded-via-xml-serialization for a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add your default constructor and set it there. Here is an example:

```
public MyObject()
{
    Flag = true;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure what's going on in your code, but this works perfectly fine:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject()
        {
            Flag = true;
        }

        public bool Flag { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

First, I didn't have the bool property there and serialized it to a file.. then for step 2, I added that bool property and the constructor.. then deserialized it from disk and it showed `true`, which is what I expected.

Please review your code, as I expect something else is going on. If you need help, post the full class here.

Comment: thanks for your reply... but after adding constructor still it set the flag value to false :(

Comment: That's very odd.. because I just tried it here and it worked perfectly fine. Can you post your entire class?

Comment: Matt, you're code cant work. When deserializing, the constructor is not called.

Comment: @Polity, please don't tell me my code cant work when I tested it myself. Next time, it would be better if you try it yourself first before commenting. Thanks.